# convert TSQL query to MySQL

Tags: mysql, t-sql, phpmyadmin

I need to convert this tSQL query into MySQL query version 5.7.14
I tried declare parameter with the following syntax

```
declare @commissionType INT;
```

but I reached a dead end and need help to convert this query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
@chainId int
as 
BEGIN
    declare @commissionMethod int
    declare @commissionType int
    declare @value decimal(18,2)

    set @commissionMethod = 1
    set @value = 200000
    set @commissionType = (select  CommissionType from CommissionRules 
    where ChainId = @chainId )

        IF(@commissionMethod = 1)
        BEGIN
            print('alert')
            select (Fixed * @value) / 100 from CommissionRules where ChainId = @chainId  
        END
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much a literal conversion.  But check your logic.  It doesn't make any sense.   `v_commissionMethod` is always 1 and `v_commissionType` is not even being used after selecting a value.

```
 DELIMITER //

    CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc (
    p_chainId int)
    BEGIN
        declare v_commissionMethod int;
        declare v_commissionType int;
        declare v_value decimal(18,2);

        set v_commissionMethod = 1;
        set v_value = 200000;
        select  CommissionType into v_commissionType from CommissionRules 
        where ChainId = p_chainId ;

            IF(v_commissionMethod = 1)
            THEN
                /* print('alert') */
                select (Fixed * v_value) / 100 from CommissionRules where ChainId = p_chainId;  
            END IF;
    END;
    //

    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and just to be clear, the code is just a simplify to take a glimpse of how to convert Tsql to Mysql.. and how to declare variables, parameters and IF conditions..
bytheway, I managed my code, and I'll get back to you if it didn't work well, otherwise I'll close the question and chose it as a correct answer..
thanks again

Comment: thanks a lot, everything works great except 1 query  -  **select applycalc into v_apply from comsteps where comid = v_comid AND calcfrom > v_value and v_value <= calcto ;**  -   I don't know why? even though it worked great in SQL tab  -  **select applycalc as v_apply from comsteps where comid  = 12 AND calcfrom > 150 <= calcto**   - any suggestions ?

Comment: @Hossam  by not working did you mean there is a syntax error? Syntax looks ok though.  Perhaps variables are not declared?

Comment: **Error code: 1329, SQLState: 02000, Message: No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed** but I'm sure there is a data, because it gives me result from SQL tab!!

Comment: I got it, it should be **select applycalc into v_apply from comsteps where comid = v_comid AND calcto >= v_value AND v_value > calcfrom;**  - beside that, I've put a handler  -  **DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_apply = 0;**

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc (
    in_chainId unsigned
) as 
BEGIN
    select v_CommissionType := CommissionType,
           v_commissionMethod = 1,
           v_value = 200000
    from CommissionRules 
    where ChainId = in_chainId;

    if v_commissionMethod = 1 then
        select 'alert';

        select (Fixed * v_value) / 100
        from CommissionRules
        where ChainId = in_chainId  
    end if;
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc (
    in_chainId unsigned
) as 
BEGIN
    ' at line 1